# jqGrid dataUrl not returning value from server

Tags: jqgrid

I am using `dataUrl` to populate my dropdown in form edit of jqGrid, but i am not getting any response from server. what am i missing? fiddler shows no error

```js
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: "CurrencySetting.aspx/GetDet",
    buildSelect: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
        var data = typeof response === "string" ?
                           $.parseJSON(response.responseText) : response;
        s = "<select>";

        s += '<option value="0">------</option>';
        $.each(data, function () {
        s += '<option value="1">' + this.CurrencyCd +
                   '</option>';
        });
        return s + "</select>";
    }
}
```

server code:

```cs
public static string GetDet()
        {
            SysDataContext db = new SysDataContext();
            var query = (from SC in db.SysCurrencySettings
                         select new
                         {
                            SC.CurrencyCd
                         }).ToList();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
        }
```

HTTP response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 11:10:23 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 15497
Connection: Close
```

Comment: You should **always** write which version of jqGrid you use. The HTTP response which you included contains only headers, but no data. It seems that the response contains HTML code instead of JSON data. Could you include full response. The C# code don't contains any attributes. Typically one uses at least `[WebMethod]` attribute. You don't use any options of `editoptions` to set `contentType` to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` or `"application/json"`. `string GetDet()` should be replaced to `object GetDet()`. You should replace `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);` to `return query;`

Comment: Please examine how I changed formatting of code of your question and use the same formation in the future. You should change the code of `buildSelect` to set the same value of `value=` attribute and the text of `<option>`: `s += '<option value="' + this.CurrencyCd + '">' + this.CurrencyCd + '</option>';`

Comment: @oleg : yes the code is returning complete HTML code of the page even after adding {ajaxSelectOptions: {contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }. I did change GetDet signature and the option value also. sorry i missed the [webmethod] attribute while posting

Comment: I'm not sure **where exactly in your code you added `ajaxSelectOptions`**. What kind of text is in HTML body of the response to `GetDet`? Is it probably an error message or the response with CurrencyCd which is just wrong encoded? You should include more details about the code which you use, where one see `ajaxSelectOptions` and it's clear which editing mode you use. You should include always the version of jqGrid which you use too because jqGrid options are different in different versions.